# How to get the Keys in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey there i am trying to get the random generated key of datasets from a firebase. 
like this:

projects
 ---12345
 ---67890
...

i just would like to get the key and safe it to another part in the Database.

I tried that:
but it gives me everything under the node.

```
getKEY(){ 
    firebase.database().ref('project').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Key" +  JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())  )       
 });
}
```

can some one help me out with that? How to get only the Key generated by firebase?

[image]

i would like to get these Keys and save it to another dataset but i don't know how to access them?

Comment: There is no way through the JavaScript SDK to get the keys without also getting the data under it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442546/firebase-retrieve-child-keys-but-not-values

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
getKEY(){ 
firebase.database().ref('project').once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var keys=child.key;   
  });   
 });
}
```

more info here:

[key property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer but it gives me an error with in function(child)